# how can I clone the current object in a click handler in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically add textfield to the webform. There is 'add' icon beside the existing textfield. when clicking the icon, a new combination of 'add' icon and textfield are added. Then, it is the same situation with the new 'add' icon. How can do that in javascript or jquery framework?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `clone()` method to clone an element.

```
$("#add").live("click", function(ev){
    var clone = $(ev.target).clone();
    //Add the clone to the document, eg: clone.appendTo("body");
})
```

See also: [JQuery Docs - Clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: Yup. Using .live() (or my preference, .delegate()) you don't need to clone the event, making this a slightly more elegant option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming something like:

```
<div><input><button>add</button></div>
```

Then try:

```
var elm;
$('button').click(function() {
    elm = $(this).parent();
    elm.after( elm.clone(true) );
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KL7QZ/2/

Passing `true` in the `.clone` method also clones events.

Comment: I add a remove button and handler to it, like the following:
<div><input><button id="add">add</button><button id="remove">remove</button></div>
$('#add').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().after( $(this).parent().clone(true) );
    });

    $('#remove').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
ite seems the remove functionality does not work. can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Don’t use IDs when cloning elements